# It is possible rewrite the Document property and reinject the HTML of a page by TWebBrowser?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe, twebbrowser

I have three functions below to get and set the HTML, the first function captures the HTML DOM, the second function captures the original HTML page, since the last function injects a new code in the TWebBrowser, but does the way I want and need.

After injecting a new code runs successfully, but only visually, when I click with the right button and visualize source code opens the notepad and instead of DOM code I see the code of the page.

Is there any way to rewrite the original HTML?

Get HTML Source Code (DOM).

```
function GetHTML( WebBrowser : TWebBrowser ) : String;
var
  HTMLElement : IHTMLElement;
begin
  Result := '';
  if Assigned( WebBrowser.Document ) then begin
    HTMLElement := ( WebBrowser.Document as IHTMLDocument2 ).body;
    if Assigned( HTMLElement ) then begin
      while HTMLElement.parentElement <> nil do begin
        HTMLElement := HTMLElement.parentElement;
      end;
      Result := HTMLElement.outerHTML;
    end else begin
      Result := ( WebBrowser.Document as IHTMLDocument2 ).all.toString;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Get HTML Source Code ("Original HTML").

```
function GetWebBrowserHTML( Const WebBrowser : TWebBrowser ) : String;
var
  LStream            : TStringStream;
  Stream             : IStream;
  LPersistStreamInit : IPersistStreamInit;
begin
  if not Assigned( WebBrowser.Document ) then exit;
  LStream := TStringStream.Create( '' );
  try
    LPersistStreamInit := WebBrowser.Document as IPersistStreamInit;
    Stream             := TStreamAdapter.Create( LStream, soReference );
    LPersistStreamInit.Save( Stream, true );
    Result := LStream.DataString;
  finally LStream.Free( );
  end;
end;
```

Rewrite HTML Source Code (only visually apparent).

```
procedure WBAppendHTML( WB : SHDocVw.TWebbrowser;const HTML : string );
var
  Doc      : MSHTML.IHTMLDocument2;
  BodyElem : MSHTML.IHTMLBodyElement;
  Range    : MSHTML.IHTMLTxtRange;
begin
  if not SysUtils.Supports( WB.Document, MSHTML.IHTMLDocument2, Doc ) then begin
    Exit;
  end;
  if not SysUtils.Supports( Doc.body, MSHTML.IHTMLBodyElement, BodyElem ) then
  begin
    Exit;
  end;
  Range := BodyElem.createTextRange;
  Range.collapse( False );
  Range.pasteHTML( HTML );
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I know of is to download the HTML from the webserver yourself and alter it as needed (which includes inserting a `<base href`> tag into the `<head>` so relative links can be resolved), and then load the altered HTML into the `TWebBrowser` via its `IPersisteStreamInit.load()` method (if there is no `Document` loaded yet, navigate the `TWebBrowser` to the `"about:blank"` URL first).